# Drop all indexes from all collections in a MongoDB database using the command line

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodump, mongorestore

I've used mongorestore to restore a database but I'm getting an error that the index already exists when I try to run my application.

I know of the function db.collection.dropIndex() but is there a way to automate this and drop all indexes from all collections in a database at once?

I've tried

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(col_name) {   
   var coll = db.getCollection(col_name);   
   coll.dropIndexes(); 
});
```

But that doesn't do the trick.
Any ideas?

Comment: Then go with db.dropDatabase; command if you want to start with fresh database...!!!

Comment: This happened to me with my Spring application. If you're using Spring, you might try upgrading your MongoDB drivers. I think the newer drivers address this, but I'm not positive since I used the below solution to destroy, and re-create, all my indexes. If I had more time, and wasn't like "Ohhhh no! Production is down!" I'd have tried upgrading my MongoDB drivers in a controlled, testing, environment, first.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your command works for me (it drops all indexes on the currently selected DB). You can also use this alternative.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collName) { 
    db.runCommand({dropIndexes: collName, index: "*"});
});
```

When dropping indexes only non `_id` indexes will be dropped.

Workaround solution is to drop the database and set `--noIndexRestore` flag when restoring with `mongorestore` so that the indexes are not restored.

From `man mongorestore`:

> --noIndexRestore
>
> New in version 2.2.
>
> Prevents mongorestore from restoring and building indexes as specified in the corresponding mongodump output.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command to drop all the indexes from all the collections:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (d) {
   db[d].dropIndexes();
});
```

Try this!

[Reference link](https://gist.github.com/piscis/3b3df53241fdbb859c07)